# Boostrap dropdown using input text

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to find out if it is possible, or been done already, to have a dropdown appear when a user clicks in a input text box with Bootstrap? I have explored SO and Google but have not come up with the right answers I am looking for.

If my question is not clear enough, I can mock up something visual of what I am looking to accomplish and add if needed.

Comment: Did you already try it? Give us code. :3

Comment: Select2? https://select2.github.io/

Comment: @FelippeDuarte Add that as answer please so I can accept

Comment: Always appreciate the down votes. I forget about the saying that "no question is stupid" :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use select2, check here: https://select2.github.io/